# How long can I keep my carafe on the warmer?

Tags: flavor, drip-brew

I've heard that the heater plate of my coffee maker will give my coffee a "burnt" aftertaste. But about how long do I have after brewing? Is the effect more or less immediate, or will the effect not be noticeable for a few hours?

I'm using a [Cuisinart DCC-2650](https://www.cuisinart.com/products/coffee_makers/dcc-2650.html) with an adjustable warmer.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a solution to your problem that I use is a good thermos. It sits right next to my coffee maker and when the brew is done I pour it into the thermos. This keeps it hot for hours and avoids the burnt taste. Also saves electricity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would depend on a number or factors including temperature of the warmer and humidity in the room.  However, personally, I can begin to taste a difference after as little as 45 minutes on the warmer.  I tend to drink two cups of coffee pretty quickly to avoid this.

Coffee is a product always best fresh, but how long before your palate can detect that it isn't fresh any longer is a matter that varies by individual.  My wife will drink coffee from a pot that has been sitting for four hours plus; after about an hour and a half I'll throw the pot away and make another.  Your own mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is to keep coffee warm through insulation. If you have a decent thremos it'll keep coffee warm for a very long time. I had a thermos which could keep the contents above 170F for almost 4 hours.

Comment: We had a thermos carafe from a previous Cuisinart coffee maker. It actually fits in the new one (they have the same dimensions, though the thermos has a smaller capacity), so we've started using that. I'm a little worried about the heater plate with the metal carafe, but it has a flat bottom (such that it doesn't "nest") and the plate appears to have a weight sensor, so I don't think it's going to burn. Just in case, we turn the coffee maker off as soon as it's done brewing.

Comment: Yeah, I would be careful, as the insulation inside the carafe could melt if heated too much.

Answer (score 0):

Coffee that is cooled to room temperature can be stored for a surprisingly long time. Coffee drinks which are commercially "canned" keep for months. A coffee buddy (a restaurant trained chef and coffee nut) would make coffee at home once a week, keep it in the fridge, and microwave it as needed.

I'm a coffee snob, but I would never turn down his coffee.

"Fresh" doesn't depend on the time since brewing. It depends on the temperature at which it has been held. 30 minutes on the hot plate is worse than a week in the 'fridge.